# De Morgan's Law negation example

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I was going through Discrete Mathematics by Kenneth H Rosen, there was an example explaining the logical equivalence of De Morgan's law which i do not completely understand, the example is as below

[image]

Shouldn't the negation of "Miguel has a cellphone and he has a laptop computer" be Miguel does not have a cellphone and a laptop computer. How is the proposition that he has one of them the negation of the above proposition which implies he has both gadgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negation of "Miguel has a cell phone and he has a laptop computer" is "Miguel does not have both a cell phone and a laptop computer," which means "Miguel doesn't have a cell phone or (meaning and/or) Miguel doesn't have a laptop computer."  The highlighted sentence doesn't say he has one of those things.  It says he's missing at least one of them.

Comment: But missing at least one could mean he can have one of them which would not be a true negation of the original proposition?

Comment: @Shivam, yes, it is a negation of the original, as it and the original can't both be true.

Comment: @Shivam If he has one of them (but not the other!), then the original statement is false.

Comment: ok if you think like that i think it is correct, i was just thinking in terms of everything or nothing as nothing is like negation of everything....didn't think something can be considered as negation of everything.

Comment: @ShivamSingh  It seems like you are confusing the *negation* of a statement with the *opposite* of a statement.  Consider the statement: [P is true and Q is true].  The negation of that statement is [P is false **or** Q is false (or both)].  The opposite of the original statement is (instead) [P is false **and** Q is false].

Comment: @ShivamSingh Negating a sentence is analogous to taking the complement of a set.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes sir you are correct, thank you so much for clearing that, i see where i went wrong :) . Thanks everyone, much appreciated